# Add 2nd level element to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I've got an XML file:

```
<uploads>
  <upload backupid="3">
    XXXXXXXXX
  </upload>
</uploads>
```

How do I add an element (or even more) in place of `XXX` (for given `backupid`)?

```
<file filename="XXX">HASH-CODE</file>
```

I've tried with following:

```
public static void AddFileToExistingUpload(int lastUsedID, string fileName, string generatedHash)
{
    var xdoc = LoadUploadsXML();
    var element = xdoc.Elements("upload").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("backupid").Value.Equals(lastUsedID));
    element.Add(new XElement("file", generatedHash, new XAttribute("filename", fileName)));
    SaveUploadXML(xdoc);
}
```

But all I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred

Comment: At which point are you getting the null reference exception. Can you post a stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

The `xdoc` has only an `uploads` element, `upload` is under that:

```
 var element = xdoc.Element("uploads").Elements("upload").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("backupid").Value.Equals(lastUsedID));
```

or insert `Root` instead:

```
 var element = xdoc.Root.Elements("upload").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("backupid").Value.Equals(lastUsedID));
```

or use `Descendants`:

```
    var element = xdoc.Descendants("upload").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("backupid").Value.Equals(lastUsedID));
```